# How to get the C# code support in vs2015 editor to work again?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I recently updated my visual studio 2015 to the update 3. But since then I am not getting the C# code support in visual studio any more. I mean that in my code they are no more colors or completion anymore. I received an error about C sharp compiler but now i can't find it is not poppin out anymore.

I realized that in the properties related to the text editor in VS2015 there is and error about Intellisense and advanced code style formatting and it says that there is an error loading these properties.

Please some help. At least help me to get the error message back.

Comment: Would you be opposed to just trying a clean reinstall? Without knowing the error it's going to be really hard, if not impossible to help you without randomly guessing at the issue.

Comment: I dont have time for this.

Comment: @BrootsWaybm is absolutely correct.. I have spent DAYS trying to figure out why something in visual studio quit working.  Uninstall and re-install will take you FAR LESS time to complete.  I ALSO had this issue and I too was in a pinch.  Use another code editor in tandem with VS until you have time to fix it.

Comment: Updates are notorious for changing settings. Try this: Go to Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> All Languages -> General and enable "Auto list members".

Comment: @EdneyHolder it is already enabled

Comment: I did reinstall my visual studio properly but it still doesn't work. :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not about reinstalling properly visual studio or not it seems like when you moved to visual studio 2015 update 3 
3 somethong went wrong. 
To get back your C# support in the Editor

1. Open visual studio.
2. Open the tool menu
3. Extension and udpdates
4. There is most likely somethong in the queue. Do all of pending updates.
5. Enjoy your C# support